# HTML\JavaScript - News Scroller - Sliding Text Effect

Tags: html, css, dhtml, slideshow

how can i make this....

[goto this link and see the text sliding after regular intervals](http://www.scriptocean.com/dticker.html)

well i want to learn to make this so that i could make **this**
[image]...

it is supposed to be a dynamic news scroller.... but to make this i know i will have to learn the thingy on the link that i gave you... then the next steps are going to take me to **dynamic news scroller**

**PARDON** my so abstract question, actually i don't have any knowledge about this or what this methodology\technique... so i need some leads on how to learn to make this... i have been experimenting with JavaScript set Timeout function but that didn't work...

so the leads

- what is this thing called.. so i could google it... like drop down menus are called `CSS Drop Down Menus` or `Flash Drop Down Menus` etcetra
- or can anybody post link to some tutorials in domain of  HTML, DHTML, CSS, JavaScript & PHP.. cuz thats what i know
- or some-generous-body could throw in some code or some functions required for this to get me started learnin' this

p.s. **HOW TO MAKE TEXT AFTER REGULAR INTERVALS WITH SLIDE-IN & OUT ANIMATION**

Comment: guys don't vote down not exactly programming question but....   hey  already apologized in the question

Comment: Why not view the HTML, JavaScript, and CSS source at your example site?

Comment: i did.. there's nothing... OR i was unable to figure it out

Comment: IMO, it's called a [Carousel](http://www.google.com/#q=carousel+javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hey you can use, jQuery Cycle plugin:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/after.html

it have many option to perform your task...

Comment: is this only for images.. do i have add some library... i don't know jQuery... my domain is HTML, JavaScript, PHP.. but i am eager to learn if its not going to take much time... cuz on Monday this thing has to be live

Comment: no... text can also be animated.
I also created a demo for u, check out: 

http://jsfiddle.net/2G28Z/1/

Comment: @Moon: You can cycle everyhing, not only images. You can even build your own pagination handler. It is very powerful. Just check out the examples.

Comment: @vaibhav: a little more favor... i don't know jQuery man... so please tell me which JS library to add, where to get it...

Comment: @Moon: the required js library appears to be jQuery 1.4.2 (I'd recommend linking to Google's hosted version, info here: http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery). To enable autoplay add an integer value to the `timeout` (replace the 0 with a 1000 for a one-second pause before auto-scrolling).